# Is there any API that can directly get the relationship between two nodes in neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

i want to get the relationship between two specified nodes, though i hava writed a customed function for my program ,but maybe there is an official API can do this, so ,if you konw the API ,please tell me . 3Q...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second @Pangea for the Cypher example.

In the Java API you would do:

```
for (Relationship r : n1.getRelationships()) {
   if (r.getOtherNode(n1).equals(n2)) return r;
}
```

You would start from the node you know has fewer relationships. This is subject to change in Neo4j 2.1.

Comment: think you, i like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say `n1` and `n2` represent the given two nodes with id's 100 and 200 respectively, then the below query would return the relationship `r` between those two.

```
START n1=node(100), n2=node(200)
WITH n1-[r]-n2
RETURN r;
```